# Animate Sprite while is moving andengine

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine, move

I wanna animate a sprite while I'm moving with DigitalController. I have the next code, and works fine to move the player:

```
@Override
public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
    //Evitar que se salga
    int velocidad = 200;

    if(pValueX>0) {//Derecha
        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, true);
    } else {
        if(pValueX<0){//Izquierda
            player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
            }
    }

    /* Sin salir de la cámara */ 
    if (player.getX()<=0) { 
            player.setX(player.getWidth());
    } else if((player.getX()+player.getWidth())>=CAMERA_WIDTH){
            player.setX(CAMERA_WIDTH-(player.getWidth()*2));
    }

    physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * velocidad, pValueY);
}
```

If pValue is 1.0 is right, If pvalueX is -1.0 is left, I don't wanna move up or down, only left/right. The problem is that player.animate starts when I untap the joystick, and I wanna starts WHILE I'm tapping joystick.

Answer (score 1):

Hi resolve my problem.

The idea is use sprite.isAnimationRunning() and set loop on animations to false:

```
if(!player.isAnimationRunning())
                if(pValueX>0){//Derecha
                    player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 0, 2, false);
                }else{
                    if(pValueX<0){//Izquierda
                        player.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, false);
                    }
                }
```